# when quadratic form restricted to tangent plane of surface is degenerate

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, quadratic-forms

Consider the one-sheeted hyperbola $X= \{ x^2 -y^2 -z^2=-1 \}$ with quadratic form $q(x,y,z) = x^2 -y^2 -z^2$. I want to understand when $q$ restricted to the tangent plane $T_pX$ for $p \in X$ is degenerate. And I am hoping to have an approach that will generalize to (anti-)de sitter space.

So here is my attempt to work out the details, but I am struggling with this: Let $p \in X$, $p= (x_0, y_0, z_0)$. Then the normal to the tangent plane at that point is $(2x_0, -2y_0, -2z_0)$. And so $T_pX$ is the plane $2x_0(x-x_0) -2y_0(y-y_0) -2z_0(z-z_0) =0$. And so I want to determine what values of $(x,y,z)$ on $T_pX$ also make the quadratic form 0.

Plugging in equations would be really messy and I don't think give a good picture or lend itself to a generalization, and so I was thinking alternatively, I can think about it more geometrically: by considering the null cone, $C= \{ x^2 -y^2 -z^2=0 \}$. If one of the basis vectors of $T_pX$ lives in the null cone, (centered at $p$), then $q$ should be degenerate. (Right?). So then, one way this could occur, is if $T_pX$ and $T_pC$ have the same normal vectors. Is this a correct approach?

In addition, I am wondering if someone can give a particular example of where $q$ is degenerate, and an intuitive/geometric description of understanding where/why this happens?

And a final question is if there is a better way to do this, one that will lend itself easily toward classifying where on $X$ the quadratic form vanishes?

And finally finally, what is actually happening geometrically when this happens? Why do we often times want to rule this out?

Comment: Observe that the null cone (centered at the origin) is the asymptotic cone of the hyperboloid. If you draw a picture of the situation, you will convince yourself that it is never the case that the tangent plane to the hyperboloid coincides with the tangent plane of the (translated) null cone, in other words they never have the same normal. However, it is clear that the tangent plane to the hyperboloid intersects the local null cone along two directions at every point, so it is always degenerate.